# Definiton of function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Are these two statements true about the definition of a function $f$ from $A$ into $B$

1. For every element $a \in A$, there exists at least one element $b \in B$ such that $f(a)=b$
2. For every element $a \in A$, there exists at most one element $b \in B$ such that $f(a)=b$

Comment: Most people consider the combination of both of them to be the definition of a function.

Comment: so they are both true? strictly speaking, I think only combination of them is true. If they are stated separately, true or wrong?

Comment: Both are true..

Comment: As far as I observe that, those are _equivalent_ to the definition of a function.

Answer (score 4):

The standard (Bourbaki) definition (which is said to be canonical) of a function from a set $X$ to $Y$ is: a function is $(f,X,Y)$ with $f\subset X\times Y$ such that for every $x\in X$ there is a unique $y\in Y$ with $(x,y)\in f$ (it is common to write $y=f(x)$ for the statement $(x,y)\in f$).

Thus both 1. and 2. are correct ("unique"="there is at least one and at most one").